# Authorization - Spring boot: RestTemplate + ApacheClient + JWT

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

I use spring boot resttemplate and delegate http communication to Apache HttpClient library. I have service A and B deployed in openshift which need to interact with service C. Service C is behind Kong Gateway and authentication is based on SSO and an identity server providing JWT access tokens, with refresh tokens as well.

My question is regarding authentication from Service A or B to C. Once authenticated in A or B, what is best mechanism to store securely JWT token in A and B? I was thinking of a cache or in service A and B or database and I understand for each service we need to store tokens separately. Is it a good practice to keep using refresh token forever, or to re-authenticate and get new tokens In intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Its the responsibility of the `Authorisation` server to issue `JWT` tokens to the clients which they send in every request. Now its client's responsibility to store the tokens. So, you ideally need both the services `A` and `B` to store their tokens respectively as they would be different for both of them. [Here is more on using authorisation with JWT](https://www.leanix.net/en/blog/authorization-authentication-with-microservices).

Comment: Hi, I agree, my question was more towards best and secure storage method of JWT token in a java service, and also about refresh token usage  whether to keep using it indefinitely in client services or the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may come across this, we solved it using in-memory cache in each pod, which means each pod will get the token and keep it and evict it just before token expiry. Here rather than taking action when a token get expired and then query for new token, we proactively evict the cache "token" entry and retrieve new token.

We used **caffeine** as in-memory cache for storing the tokens.